# I get NotImplementedError when trying to do a prepared statement with mysql python connector

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-connector-python

I want to use prepared statements to insert data into a MySQL DB (version 5.7) using python, but I keep getting a NotImplementedError.
I'm following the documentation here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursorprepared.html

Using Python 2.7 and version 8.0.11 of mysql-connector-python library:

```
pip show mysql-connector-python
---
Metadata-Version: 2.1
Name: mysql-connector-python
Version: 8.0.11
Summary: MySQL driver written in Python
Home-page: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/index.html
```

This is a cleaned version (no specific hostname, username, password, columns, or tables) of the python script I'm running:

```
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector.cursor import MySQLCursorPrepared

connection = mysql.connector.connect(user=username, password=password,
                                      host='sql_server_host',
                                      database='dbname')
print('Connected! getting cursor')
cursor = connection.cursor(cursor_class=MySQLCursorPrepared)
select = "SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE column1 = ?"
param = 'param1'
print('Executing statement')
cursor.execute(select, (param,))
rows = cursor.fetchall()
for row in rows:
    value = row.column1
print('value: '+ value)
```

I get this error when I run this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 18, in <module>
    cursor.execute(select, (param,))
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mysql/connector/cursor.py", line 1186, in execute
    self._prepared = self._connection.cmd_stmt_prepare(operation)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mysql/connector/abstracts.py", line 969, in cmd_stmt_prepare
    raise NotImplementedError
NotImplementedError
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[CEXT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-cext.html) will be [enabled by default if you have it](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-connector-python/blob/0e84955ecfb53d3b477584557e8345c6427a1493/lib/mysql/connector/__init__.py#L33), and [prepared statements are not supported in CEXT at the time of writing](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=77780).

You can disable the use of CEXT when you connect by adding the keyword argument `use_pure=True` as follows:

```
connection = mysql.connector.connect(user=username, password=password,
                                     host='sql_server_host',
                                     database='dbname',
                                     use_pure=True)
```

Support for prepared statements in CEXT will be included in the upcoming `mysql-connector-python` 8.0.17 release (according to the [MySQL bug report](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=77780)). So once that is available, upgrade to at least 8.0.17 to solve this without needing `use_pure=True`.

Comment: Thanks! What an obscure thing. They really should mention it in their documentation on the prepared statements page.