# Apche Airflow with MySQL backend - UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x80 in position 0: invalid start byte

Tags: mysql, sqlalchemy, character-encoding, airflow

When I click on the DAG name or show tree view or graph view for active DAGs, I get the following error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x80 in position 0: invalid start byte

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/airflowenv/airflow1/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1988, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/home/airflowenv/airflow1/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1641, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/home/airflowenv/airflow1/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1544, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/home/airflowenv/airflow1/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 33, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/home/airflowenv/airflow1/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1639, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/home/airflowenv/airflow1/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1625, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/home/airflowenv/airflow1/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/flask_admin/base.py", line 69, in inner
    return self._run_view(f, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/airflowenv/airflow1/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/flask_admin/base.py", line 368, in _run_view
    return fn(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/airflowenv/airflow1/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/flask_login.py", line 755, in decorated_view
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/airflowenv/airflow1/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/www/utils.py", line 219, in view_func
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/airflowenv/airflow1/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/www/utils.py", line 125, in wrapper
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/airflowenv/airflow1/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/www/views.py", line 1162, in tree
    DR.execution_date>=min_date)
  File "/home/airflowenv/airflow1/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 3233, in all
    return list(self)
  File "/home/airflowenv/airflow1/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 3389, in __iter__
    return self._execute_and_instances(context)
  File "/home/airflowenv/airflow1/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 3414, in _execute_and_instances
    result = conn.execute(querycontext.statement, self._params)
  File "/home/airflowenv/airflow1/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 982, in execute
    return meth(self, multiparams, params)
  File "/home/airflowenv/airflow1/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py", line 293, in _execute_on_connection
    return connection._execute_clauseelement(self, multiparams, params)
  File "/home/airflowenv/airflow1/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1101, in _execute_clauseelement
    distilled_params,
  File "/home/airflowenv/airflow1/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1250, in _execute_context
    e, statement, parameters, cursor, context
  File "/home/airflowenv/airflow1/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1478, in _handle_dbapi_exception
    util.reraise(*exc_info)
  File "/home/airflowenv/airflow1/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 153, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/home/airflowenv/airflow1/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1246, in _execute_context
    cursor, statement, parameters, context
  File "/home/airflowenv/airflow1/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 588, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
  File "/home/airflowenv/airflow1/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/mysql/connector/cursor_cext.py", line 272, in execute
    self._handle_result(result)
  File "/home/airflowenv/airflow1/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/mysql/connector/cursor_cext.py", line 163, in _handle_result
    self._handle_resultset()
  File "/home/airflowenv/airflow1/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/mysql/connector/cursor_cext.py", line 651, in _handle_resultset
    self._rows = self._cnx.get_rows()[0]
  File "/home/airflowenv/airflow1/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection_cext.py", line 318, in get_rows
    else self._cmysql.fetch_row()
SystemError: <built-in method fetch_row of _mysql_connector.MySQL object at 0x1e9ce60> returned a result with an error set
```

I am using Airflow (version 1.8.1) with MySQL 8 as the backend database. These dags worked when I used sqlite and Oracle.

After some research on stackoverflow I made these changes to airflow config fil but this hasn't resolved the problem.

```
sql_alchemy_conn = mysql+mysqlconnector://<user>:<password>i@localhost/MIAF?charset=utf8mb4

sql_engine_encoding = utf8mb4
```

How do I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was caused by the column conf in the table dag_run which has a datatype of blob. This issue was similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52759667/properly-getting-blobs-from-mysql-database-with-mysql-connector-in-python) and answer that worked for me was to use use_pure option.

I fixed the issue by editing the sql_alchemy_conn in file airflow.cfg.

```
sql_alchemy_conn = mysql+mysqlconnector://<user>:<password>i@localhost/MIAF?use_pure=True
```

P.S. I worked it out by writing all the queries in a log file by editing the file /mysql/connector/cursor_cext.py

```
        f = open("/home/airflow/mysql_utf8_error.log","a")
        f.write(operation)
        f.write("\n")
        f.close()
```

I looked at the query that was executed when the failure occurred and it was a fetch from dag_run.

Comment: But `BLOB` accepts any bytes.  `80` is not a valid utf8 byte; it sounds like non-utf8 text is trying to be stored into a non-blob column.